# Scanf the null value (ASCII)

Tags: c

I want to ask how can I scanf a letter that has value 0x00 (I know its null). I call my function echo -e '\x00' | function /.myfunction and I need to scanf it into a string for fprinting it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I scanf a letter that has value 0x00

Sure, with input <kbd>Null Character</kbd><sup>1</sup> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  `"%s"` treats a *null character* like any other non-white-space character.

```
char s[2];
scanf("%1s", s);
```

will nicely make `s[0] == '\0'` (due to input *null character*) and `s[1] == '\0'` due to the appended *null character*.

Subsequent code will likely have trouble working with `s[]` as a *string* though.  You may want a new approach with `"%c"` or `getchar()`.    Suggest an array of characters with an accompanying *length*, rather than a *string*.

---

If **required** to use `scanf()`, then keep track of the length with `"%n"`.

```
char buf[100];
int n1,n2
if (scanf(" %n%99s%n2", &n1, buf, &n2) == 1) {
  int length_read = n2 - n1;
  for (int i=0; i<length_read; i++) {
    if (isprint((unsigned char) buf[i])) {
      printf("%c", buf[i]);
    } else {
      // do something special for non-printable characters.
      printf("(%X)", (unsigned char) buf[i]);
    } 
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <kbd>Null Character</kbd> may be difficult to enter directly other than piping as OP is using.  Some keyboards allow <kbd>Crtl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks you very much, i didnt know about %n! i will remember it. <3